# how to add file in j2me simulator file system

Tags: file, java-me, simulator, file-browser

I am trying to send file in xmpp, for that i need to make user to select file in phone
I am using file chooser that i have created, I want to put jpg file in simulator(DefaultColorphone) file system but unable to do so,I tried  putting file to this path

```
mytoolkit\appdb\DefaultColorPhone\filesystem
```

but not working....

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try mytoolkit\appdb\DefaultColorPhone\filesystem\root1

UPD: Check root folders for simulator's filesystem

```
Enumeration roots = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
    while(roots.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println((String)roots.nextElement());
    }
```